# Solving 3 equations involving trigonometric expressions.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have a question which was asked in IMO,

> Solve the system of equations:
>
> $x \sin a+y\sin 2a+z\sin 3a=\sin 4a$
>
> $x \sin b+y\sin 2b+z\sin 3b=\sin 4b$.
>
> $x \sin c+y\sin 2c+z\sin 3c=\sin 4c$.

I am clueless at it, any hint/help is appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: what are the varibles?

Comment: I have added another proof.

Comment: Thanks @jeanmarie. And sorry too as I can not accept your answer twice. :) :p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that the initial system has a non-zero determinant (see remark below for a discussion).

Let us consider the following system:

$$\tag{1}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x e^{ia} + y e^{2ia} + ze^{3ia}&=e^{4ia}\\
x e^{ib} + y e^{2ib} + ze^{3ib}&=e^{4ib}\\
x e^{ic} + y e^{2ic} + ze^{3ic}&=e^{4ic}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\qquad\iff\qquad
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
x + y e^{ia} + z e^{2ia} &=  e^{3ia}\\
x + y e^{ib} + z e^{2ib} &=  e^{3ib}\\
x + y e^{ic} + z e^{2ic} &=  e^{3ic}
\end{aligned}\end{cases}
$$

Let us define polynomial $P(T):=x+yT+zT^2-T^3$.

With this notation, system $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$P(e^{ia})=P(e^{ib})=P(e^{ic})=0.$$

The three roots of $P$ being $e^{ia}$, $e^{ib}$, $e^{ic}$, Vieta's formulas give:

$$\tag{2}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
x&= \phantom{-}e^{ia}e^{ib}e^{ic}=e^{i(a+b+c)}\\
y&= -(e^{i(a+b)}+e^{i(a+c)}+e^{i(b+c)})\\
z&= \phantom{-}e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{ic}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$

It suffices now to take the imaginary part of system (1) whose solutions will be the imaginary parts of solutions above, i.e.,

> $$\tag{3}
>   \begin{cases}
>   \begin{aligned}
>   x&= \phantom{-}\sin(a+b+c)\\
>   y&=-\bigl(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a+c)+\sin(b+c)\bigr)\\
>   z&= \phantom{-}\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(c)
>   \end{aligned}
>   \end{cases}
>   $$

Remark: the determinant of system $(1)$, under its second form, is a Vandermonde determinant; it is non-zero unless, two values among $e^{ia}$, $e^{ib}$,  $e^{ic}$ are identical, which means two angles $a,b,c$ are equal modulo $2\pi$. This is the only case of indeterminacy.

---

**Edit**: a different proof, not using complex numbers, although using the same 3rd degree polynomial trick is as follows.

Consider the following formulas:

$$\begin{cases}\sin 2a&=&\sin a \times (2 \alpha)\\ \sin 3a&=&\sin a \times (4 \alpha^2-1)\\ \sin 4a&=&\sin a \times (8 \alpha^3-4\alpha)\end{cases} \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \  \alpha:=\cos a$$

which all are particular cases of the fact that $\frac{\sin(na)}{\sin(a)}$ can be expressed as a degree $n-1$ polynomial in $\cos(a)$ (which is named 2nd order Chebyshev polynomial).

Plugging these values of $\sin 2a$, $\sin 3a$,$\sin 4a$ in the first equation of the initial system, and simplifying by $\sin a$ (assumed non-zero) we obtain

$$x+y2\alpha+z(4 \alpha^2-1)=8 \alpha^3-4\alpha.$$

In other words,

$$8 \alpha^3-4z\alpha^2-(2y+4)\alpha+(z-x)=0$$

We can do the same for the second and third equations, with $\beta:=\cos b$ and $\gamma:=\cos c$. Gathering these 3 results, we have:

$$\tag{4}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
8 \alpha^3-4z\alpha^2-(2y+4)\alpha+(z-x)=0\\
8 \beta^3-4z\beta^2-(2y+4)\beta+(z-x)=0\\
8 \gamma^3-4z\gamma^2-(2y+4)\gamma+(z-x)=0
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

This means that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are roots of polynomial:

$$P(T):=8T^3-4zT^2-(2y+4)T+(z-x)$$

Viete's formulas give:

$$\tag{5}
  \begin{cases}
  \begin{aligned}
  z/2&=&\alpha+\beta+\gamma\\
  (2y+4)/8&=&\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha\\
  (z-x)/8&=&\alpha\beta\gamma
  \end{aligned}
  \end{cases} \ \ \ \implies$$

> $$\begin{cases}
>   \begin{aligned}
>   x&=& 2(\cos(a)+\cos(b)+\cos(c))+8\cos(a)\cos(b)\cos(c)\\
>   y&=&-2-4(\cos(a)\cos(b)+\cos(b)\cos(c)+\cos(c)\cos(a))\\
>   z&=& 2(\cos(a)+\cos(b)+\cos(c))\\
>   \end{aligned}
>   \end{cases}
>   $$

Remark: it must be understood that this is the same set of solutions as presented in the yellow cartridge above, expressed in terms of cosines instead of sines of angles $a,b,c$.

Comment: Very neat. I took the liberty of doing some reformatting.

Comment: @egreg Thank you **very** much for reformatting: it helps me a lot for improving my Latex and my scientific writing in English.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to solve for $(x, y, z)^{T}$ then

Hint: Rewrite
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin a & \sin 2a & \sin 3a\\
\sin b & \sin 2b & \sin 3b\\
\sin c & \sin 2c & \sin 3c\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sin 4a \\\sin 4b \\ \sin 4c
\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sin a & \sin 2a & \sin 3a\\
\sin b & \sin 2b & \sin 3b\\
\sin c & \sin 2c & \sin 3c\\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
\sin 4a \\\sin 4b \\ \sin 4c
\end{pmatrix}$$
The next step is to compute the inverse, using double angle formula for $\sin$.

Comment: I just  wanted to say that solving a linear system is almost never done by inverting the matrix of the system, unless this matrix has a very simple inverse.